# Convert sql query result into JSON array in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, sqlite

The result I got from SQLite in Python looks like this:

```
{"John", "Alice"}, {"John", "Bob"}, {"Jogn", "Cook"} ......
```

I want to convert the result into JSON format like this:

```
{
    "Teacher": "John",
    "Students": ["Alice", "Bob", "Cook" .....]
}
```

I used GROUP_CONCAT to concat all the students' name and the following code:

```
row_headers = [x[0] for x in cursor.description] #this will extract row headers
result = []
for res in cursor.fetchall():
    result.append(dict(zip(row_headers, res)))
```

I was able to get this result:

```
{
    "Teacher": "John",
    "Students": "Alice, Bob, Cook" 
}
```

How can I make the students into array format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of sqlite has the [JSON1](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) extension enabled, it's easy to do in pure SQL:

```
SELECT json_object('Teacher', teacher,
                   'Students', json_group_array(student)) AS result
FROM ex
GROUP BY teacher;
```

[DB Fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3NirBbRH6r5bgrVP24yW61/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `result["Students"] = result["Students"].split(", ")`.

Comment: Nice! But what if the student's name contains ',' in it?